# Passing variable name into sapply

Tags: r, variables, matrix, sapply

Here is a toy dataset:

```
df1 <-data.frame(c("267119002","257051033",NA,"267098003","267099020","267047006"))
names(df1)[1]<-"ID"

df2 <-data.frame(c("257051033","267098003","267119002","267047006","267099020"))
names(df2)[1]<-"ID"
df2$vals <-c(11,22,33,44,55)
```

and toy code:

```
fetcher <-function(x){
  y <- df2$vals[which(match(df2$ID,x)==TRUE)]
  return(y) 
}

sapply(df1$ID,function(x) fetcher(x))
```

In the `sapply` statement, instead of using `df1$ID`, I need to use a variable name. As in:

```
col <-"ID"
sapply(df1[col],function(x) fetcher(x))
```

However when I do it this way it does not iterate through all the values of `df1$ID`. This way it only does `sapply` on the first value. Example output:

```
> sapply(df1[col],function(x) fetcher(x))
ID 
33 
> sapply(df1$ID,function(x) fetcher(x))
[1] 33 11 22 55 44
```

So why is this happening? I need to use the variable name instead of the exact column name as I need to apply this to different columns that will vary each time the program runs. But I need it to apply to each row not just the first row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that `df1[col]` returns a one column dataframe and `df1$ID` returns a vector/factor. Using your code you want a vector/factor, hence you may

use `df1[, col]`

```
sapply(df1[, col],function(x) fetcher(x))
```

or double brackets `df1[[col]]`

```
sapply(df1[[col]],function(x) fetcher(x))
```

.

Comment: Brilliant thanks works perfectly! And I learned something to boot! Thanks very much Mark!